# How to implement authentication for inter module communication in my application?

Tags: security, authentication, distributed, x509

We have divided our large application into several modules and want to implement authentication system when two modules are communicating which each other in client-server fashion. We don't want the server's services accessible unless the client presents some kind of certificate or credentials. What's the industry standard or popular way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) may help you, this is a very famous and practical authentication service for open network systems

Hope helps!